# sed: convert format of date

Tags: date, sed, substitution

Fairly new to sed. I am trying to write a sed command that converts dates to the reverse, but not if they're part of other words.

So far I have:

```
sed 's/[0-9]\{1\}/[0-9]\{1\}/[0-9]\{4\}/SUBSTITUTE/g'
```

Trying to figure out the substitute part. Thank you!

Comment: i think you wrongly specified `dates from a MM/DD/YYYY format to a YYYY/MM/DD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use word boundaries.

```
sed 's~\b\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\([0-9]\{4\}\)\b~\3/\2/\1~g' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo '04/13/1991hello' | sed 's~\b\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\([0-9]\{4\}\)\b~\3/\1/\2~g'
04/13/1991hello
$ echo '02/03/2001' | sed 's~\b\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\([0-9]\{4\}\)\b~\3/\2/\1~g'
2001/03/02
```